# How to import classes in Java without eclipse?

Tags: java, macos, class, import, lwjgl

I'm sorry that this may seem like a basic question, but I need help on importing classes. I downloaded the Lightweight Java Gaming Library(LWJGL), but I don't know how to install it. When I try the test, it doesn't work.

I have a folder in which I extracted the basic LWJGL files. I now have a setup like this:

generic_folder/libs/lwjgl-2.8.3

I also have this test which I copy-pasted from the tutorial on the LWJGL wiki:
It is located in the generic_folder. When I try and javac it, it says 
DisplayExample.java:1: package org.lwjgl does not exist.

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

public class DisplayExample {

public void start() {
    try {
    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
    Display.create();
} catch (LWJGLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(0);
}

// init OpenGL here

while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

    // render OpenGL here

    Display.update();
}

Display.destroy();
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    DisplayExample displayExample = new DisplayExample();
displayExample.start();
}
```

}

Do I have to place the files in a certain location or what? Please help. Thanks!

Edit: I am sorry. I'm new to Java. Please go a little slower. Also, LWJGL is a library, so I didn't place any files inside of it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify a classpath (preferrably with the `-cp` switch) such that `java`/`javac` knows where to find the .jar files you need access to. It typically looks as follows:

For compiling:

```
javac -cp .:libs/lwjgl-2.8.3/jar/lwjgl.jar your-java-files
```

for running:

```
java -cp .:libs/lwjgl-2.8.3/jar/lwjgl.jar your-class-file
```

(Note that if you're using Windows, I believe `:` should be replaced by `;`.)

Comment: Do I have to place something instead of the .: ?

Comment: This says File not found: DisplayExample.java

Comment: Do you have the source files inside a `src` directory? go into the src directory: `cd src`, use `-cp .:../lib/....` and add the `-d ../bin` switch to write the class files to `../bin`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add that jar to your classpath when you invoke `javac`, like so:

```
javac -cp generic_folder/libs/lwjgl-2.8.3.jar path/to/java/file/DisplayExample.java
```

I'm assuming that `lwjgl-2.8.3` *is* actually a jar file.  You never specified in your question.

You'll have to once again add the jar to your classpath when you attempt to run your example:

```
java -cp generic_folder/libs/lwjgl-2.8.3.jar path/to/java/file/DisplayExample
```

Comment: Woops, forgot about that. lwjgl-2.8.3 is actually a folder with several different folders inside of it. I know where to locate the correct jar file, though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set the LWJGL folder to CLASSPATH environment. For example

set CLASSPATH=${PATH_TO}/generic_folder/libs/lwjgl-2.8.3

That should do it.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on environment variables. It makes the build process dependent on the system-configuration which might get quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When you run javac, you need to tell it where the jar file is.  You can either set you CLASSPATH environment variable or pass the location to the java compiler.  The latter is better, as you probably won't want lwjgl if you start a second java project.

To tell the java compiler directly, you would do something like

```
javac -classpath generic_folder/libs/lwjgl-2.8.3/lwjgl.jar DisplayExample.java
```

The classpath can either point to a jar file containing the classes or the top level directory containing unjared class files.  If the unjarred classes are in generic_folder/libs/lwjgl-2.8.3/classes, you would point to generic_folder/libs/lwjgl-2.8.3/classes, not generic_folder/libs/lwjgl-2.8.3/org/lwjgl

Answer (score 0):

```
javac -classpath external.jar myClass.java
```

For more info -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/5112638/5790669