# Don't understand why I'm getting the Error: Could not find or load main class from console

Tags: java, jar, classpath, itext

I have looked over several other answers on this site trying to understand why this might be happening, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I am trying to get started with iText, and .jar files in general. I downloaded and extracted the iText .jar files to a folder on my desktop: Desktop\Java\itext-5.4.4\"jar files here"

I then went to the following site:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/getting-started.html

and copied the code into Notepad. It looks like this:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/**

 */
public class HelloWorldExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document document = new Document();

        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream("HelloWorld.pdf"));

            document.open();
            document.add(new Paragraph("A Hello World PDF 

document."));
            document.close(); // no need to close 

PDFwriter?

        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I saved the file on my desktop as HelloWorldExample.java

I then went to compile my code with the following commands:

cd c:\desktop

javac -classpath Java\itext-5.4.4\itextpdf-5.4.4.jar HelloWorldExample.java

This compiled successfully

I then tried:

java -classpath Java\itext-5.4.4\itextpdf-5.4.4.jar HelloWorldExample

And I get the Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldExample error.

I have tried many variations on this including making a folder, placing a lib folder in that folder, and creating a package, but still get the same error.

What is happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure HelloWorldExample.class is in classpath specified by -classpath option of java command?

Comment: @crybird My HelloWorldExample.class is not in that directory specified by the classpath command - it is compiled to the same directory as the .java file, the desktop. I tried picking the .class file up and moving it to that folder - same error. I'm just using the commands suggested by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112607/how-to-include-libraries-in-java-without-using-an-ide), which seems to suggest this - I don't know if there is some system variable causing a problem or what.

Comment: The classpath you specified must contain your complied class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*You tried:*

```
java -classpath Java\itext-5.4.4\itextpdf-5.4.4.jar HelloWorldExample
```

*And you get the Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldExample error.*

`HelloWorldExample` is sought for in the class path. You explicitly set the classpath to merely include the iText jar in your Java call. As the iText jar surely does not include your `HelloWorldExample,` it obviously cannot be found.

I assume you work on some Windows OS (considering your choice of path separators). Thus you should try something like this to include the current directory `c:\desktop` in your Java call:

```
java -classpath Java\itext-5.4.4\itextpdf-5.4.4.jar;. HelloWorldExample
```

or

```
java -classpath Java\itext-5.4.4\itextpdf-5.4.4.jar;c:\desktop HelloWorldExample
```

Comment: This works, thanks - however, the colon is not needed on the javac command - which I think is weird.

Comment: When you compiled that source file, its file name was argument of the call. When you ran it, it's not a file name anymore but a class name to find somewhere.