# Error on importing a java external library

Tags: java, javac, vlcj

here is my .java file and the directory which contains the external .jar files.

[image: here is the directory]

[image: here is the lib folder]

Now,on compilation on terminal(Ubuntu 16.04)

I get this error:-

> package uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding does not exist

here are my two import statements

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
```

I tried entering the folder name(full path) on my import statement ,but is still doesn't work.

I successfully compiled ,buit when I try to run the file 
I get main class not found error.

Compile command
javac -cp ".:./lib/jna-3.5.2.jar/:lib/platform-3.5.2.jar/:lib/vlcj-3.8.0.jar" main.java

Run Command 
java -cp ".:./lib/jna-3.5.2.jar/:lib/platform-3.5.2.jar/:lib/vlcj-3.8.0.jar" main

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to include libraries in java without using an IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112607/how-to-include-libraries-in-java-without-using-an-ide)

Comment: tried this command for compilation (Thanks Nim) javac -cp ".:./lib/*" main.java ,still getting same error on running the class. my directory contains 6 class files ,named main ,main$1,main$2......main$5

Answer (score 0):

If your command is the one you commented in Andres' answer, then your path is wrong.
Try:

```
javac -cp ".:./lib/*" main.java
```

Comment: thanks ,it successfully compiled, on compilation ,I get this ,I get main not found error 
java -cp ".:./lib/jna-3.5.2.jar/:lib/platform-3.5.2.jar/:lib/vlcj-3.8.0.jar" main

Comment: tried this command for compilation (Thanks Nim) javac -cp ".:./lib/*" main.java ,still getting same error on running the class. my directory contains 6 class files ,named main ,main$1,main$2......main$5

Comment: Just to understand - Compilation succeeded and when using `java` to run you're having problems? If so, you need the same `-cp`

Comment: The error you're getting is main class not found, right? What is the name of the class in the file `main.java`?

Comment: It's main itself. The file name should match with classname. Don't know why am I still getting that error lol

Comment: Make sure the class is public, and has a valid main method `public static void main(String... args){`

Comment: I know  Java lol. Double checked thrice,Nvm ,will go for an IDE. Thanks for yout time Nim!