# Compilation error com.google.common.math package doesn't exist

Tags: java

[image]

```
import com.google.common.math.*;
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(IntMath.factorial(5));
    }
}
```

This is my code. I was just checking if could find any builtin function for factorial.

Comment: Please include a [mre]. For one thing, we need to know what your classpath looks like.

Comment: "i was just checking if could find any builtin function for factorial" `com.google.common.math` isn't built-in. You'd need to include Guava on your classpath.

Comment: ...for that matter, what build and dependency-management tools are you using? Maven, or anything like it?

Comment: (There isn't a builtin function for factorial in Java SE.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to include libraries in java without using an IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112607/how-to-include-libraries-in-java-without-using-an-ide)

Comment: The built-in way: `IntStream.closedRange(1, 5).reduce((a, b) -> a * b))` (doesn't handle overflow, ofc).

Comment: Yes.  Overflow is probably the reason that there isn't a built-in function too.  (20! is the largest factorial value that can be represented as a `long`.)  Which means that if you are going to do computations of (say) power series involving factorials, you will either need to use `BigDecimal` or restructure the computation.  Numerical Analysis time ...